# List of functions with $f(x)=\dfrac{d\,f(x)}{dx}$ like $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=e^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We know for $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=e^x$ the function is same as its derivative. I was wondering if there are any other such functions and how do we go about finding it?

Comment: The solution is unique, if you specify the value at a point, say $x=0$.  Then the solution is $f(x)=f(0)e^x$.

Comment: Hint: To answer to your question, you need to solve: 
$\dfrac{d\,f(x)}{dx}-f(x)=0$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) \neq 0$, then you can look at
$$ (\ln f)' = \frac{f'}{f} = 1\,, $$
and therefore
$$ \ln f(x) = x + C_0\,,$$
for some constant $C_0$. Thus the function is of the form
$$ f(x) = C e^x\,,$$
where $C = e^{C_0}$.